# Perl WSDL11 Can't Make it to Work on WSDL with XML import

Tags: xml, perl, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am a newbie to Perl programming.

In order to learn accessing a soap service, I tried to create a soap client that can connect to [this](http://www.webservicex.net/currencyconvertor.asmx?WSDL) in which I was successful to use the web service.

Now, I migrated my code to connect to my company's soap service but I encountered a problem.

"The error says that their were no port_type and no operation as well."

See code snippet below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.018;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper qw{Dumper};
use XML::Compile::SOAP11;
use XML::Compile::SOAP12;
use XML::Compile::WSDL11;

my $WsdlUrl;
my $WsdlXml;
my $SoapSrvc;
my (%SoapOps);

$WsdlUrl = "http://maxcavmes04/CamstarExternal/camstar.svc";
$WsdlXml = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($WsdlUrl);
$SoapSrvc = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new($WsdlXml);

print Dumper(\$SoapSrvc);

foreach my $SoapOp ($SoapSrvc->operations())
{
    # XML::Compile::SOAP 2.x
    if ($XML::Compile::SOAP::VERSION > 1.99)
    {
        $SoapOps{$SoapOp->name} 
            = $SoapSrvc->compileClient(operation => $SoapOp->name,
                                       port => SOAP_PORT_TYPE);
    }
    else  # XML::Compile::SOAP 0.7x
    {
        $SoapOps{$SoapOp->{operation}} 
            =  $SoapSrvc->compileClient(operation => $SoapOp->{operation},
                                        port => SOAP_PORT_TYPE);
    }
}

print "\n\n";
exit(0);
```

Investigating it further why it won't work, I use a 3rd party software called `.NET WebService Studio`. I realize from the returned of the WebService Studio that my company's Soap service uses two `WSDL` file through `WSDL:Import`.

I would like to ask from this community of how I can modify my program in order to have access to company's soap service using WSDL11.

I have also attached the dumped data of the soap service connection as reference through `print Dumper(\$SoapSrvc)` statement.

Link:
[Dumped_SoapSrvc Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_RcFVjJJ4Wlc0hDZVpoN0o3aU0/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cause can be that XML::Compile::WSDL11 doesn't load xsd's referenced from a wsdl file. You have to download your wsdl file. Read it to find references to external files like . Download referenced files check them for references... When you have everything you can use it like this:

```
my $wsdl = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new();
$wsdl->importDefinitions("first.xsd");
$wsdl->importDefinitions("second.xsd");
$wsdl->addWSDL("my_service.wsdl");
```

It would be easier to diagnose the problem if you post the wsdl file.

Comment: Please refer to link for the WSDL files. [WSDL0](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_RcFVjJJ4WlLTJ3SGI1ZGRETjA/view?usp=sharing) and [WSDL1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_RcFVjJJ4WlZVhCSmlBcG5rdzg/view?usp=sharing)