# Perl WSDL11 Can't Make it to Work on two WSDL files

Tags: xml, perl, soap, wsdl

This question is related to the issue I encountered on my Perl Program using XML::Compile::WSD11 Perl Module in which my company Webservice uses multiple WSDL with XML import.

The original post that describe this issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554734/perl-wsdl11-cant-make-it-to-work-on-wsdl-with-xml-import). From that post, I tried the suggestion of [imatveev13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4524456/imatveev13) to use the **addWSDL** API from XML::Compile::WSDL11 and the code snippet is shown below.

The two WSDL files used in the test Perl program are: [WSDL0](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_RcFVjJJ4WlLTJ3SGI1ZGRETjA/view?usp=sharing) and [WSDL1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_RcFVjJJ4WlZVhCSmlBcG5rdzg/view?usp=sharing).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.018;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper qw{Dumper};

use XML::Compile::SOAP11; # XML::Compile::SOAP 2.x
use XML::Compile::WSDL11;
use XML::Compile::Transport::SOAPHTTP;

my $WSDL0 = 'CamstarWebClient0.wsdl';
my $WSDL1 = 'CamstarWebClient1.wsdl';

# Create service proxy for web service
my $wsdlXml0 = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($WSDL0);
my $wsdlXml1 = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($WSDL1);

my $SoapSrv = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new();
$SoapSrv->addWSDL($wsdlXml0);
$SoapSrv->addWSDL($wsdlXml1);

print Dumper($SoapSrv);

# Compile all service methods
my (%SoapOps);
foreach my $SoapOp ($SoapSrv->operations)
{
    print Dumper($SoapOp);
    # XML::Compile::SOAP 2.x
    if ($XML::Compile::SOAP::VERSION > 1.99)
    {
        $SoapOps{$SoapOp->name}
            = $SoapSrv->compileClient(operation => $SoapOp->name, 
                                      port => "ICamstar");
    }
}

print "\n";
exit;
```

Running the code gave me an **error: cannot find port 'ICamstar', pick from BasicHttpBinding_ICamstar**.

I also tried without specifying the port since the service do not implement multiple port but it gave me a different error.

**Can't locate object method "_writer_body_rpcenc_hook" via package "XML::Compile::SOAP11::Client" at /usr/local/share/perl5/XML/Compile/SOAP.pm line 155**.

Appreciate any help from the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use the module `XML::Compile::SOAP11::Encoding` on top of your script:

```
use XML::Compile::SOAP11::Encoding;
```